# Loading a package as an option in a personal style file?

Tags: packages, optional-arguments

I'm sure this has been answered many times before, but all my reading has just got me more confused.  Anyway, I'm trying to create a little style file containing all my personal definitions and macros, and including a few options as to whether I do or don't want to load another package.  For example, I would like to be able to write

```
\usepackage[tikz]{mystuff}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{mystuff}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

However, I can't find a way of including the loading of a package as an option which doesn't lead to an error.  For example, this:

```
\DeclareOption{tikz}{
  \RequirePackage{tikz}
}
```

produces an error.  What's the proper way of optionally loading another package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Packages cannot be loaded inside the option part of another package.
There are several options:

- The package loading can be postponed to the end of the current package:

  ```
  \DeclareOption{tikz}{%
    \AtEndOfPackage{%
      \RequirePackage{tikz}%
    }%
  }
  ```
- A switch can be defined:

  ```
  \newif\ifmystuff@tikz
  \DeclareOption{tikz}{%
     \mystuff@tikztrue
  }
  ...
  \ProcessOptions...
  ...
  \ifmystuff@tikz
    \RequirePackage{tikz}
  \fi
  ```
- Or a macro can be defined:

  ```
  \let\mystuff@tikz\@empty
  \DeclareOption{tikz}{%
    \renewcommand*{\mystuff@tikz}{%
      \RequirePackage{tikz}%
    }%
  }
  ...
  \ProcessOptions...
  ...
  \mystuff@tikz
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I have used the first option, as it seems to me to be the simplest.  And it works perfectly.  Thanks again!